# Django Ajax - Getting KeyError while trying to access session variable

Tags: django, vue.js, axios, keyerror

I'm trying to develop custom Django Login Form. While Signing up a user, I'm setting the value of the Session variable

```
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = loads(request.body)['data']
        username = uuid.uuid1()
        emailid = data['emailid']
        password = data['password']
        if User.objects.filter(email=emailid).count() < 1:
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, emailid, password)
            user.is_active=True
            user.save()
            profile = Profile.objects.get(user = User.objects.get(username = user.username))
            profile.otp = randint(10**(6-1),(10**6)-1)
            profile.save()
            user_authenticate = authenticate(
                username=username,
                password=password
            )
            login(request, user_authenticate)
            request.session['un'] = '123456'
            print(request.session.get('un'))
            return JsonResponse({"status": "cookie set"})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"status": "error", "error": "Email ID already exists"})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"status": "ok"})
```

But, when I'm trying to get the value of request.session['un'] using

```
@csrf_exempt
def submitOtp(request):
    username = request.session.get('un')
    print(username)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if username:
            otp_generated = Profile.objects.get(user = User.objects.get(username = username))
            data = loads(request.body)['data']
            otp_submitted = data['otp']
            return JsonResponse({"otp": otp_submitted})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"otp": "not authenticated"})
```

I'm getting the value as None, and a KeyError. I'm using Axios from VueJS Front End to send Ajax Post request to Django backend.

Comment: can you show the full code where you are saving the username to the session

Comment: Updated the code...

Comment: in the first view, where you are printing the un, are you seeing that? but in the second view you are getting key error?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting KeyError. I'm using Axios, and sending Ajax request from Webpack Dev Server running at localhost:8080 to Django Server running at localhost:8000.

Comment: bro, please read my question carefully and answer. you have 2 print in 2 views, can you tell which print is printing or both are giving key error

Comment: I'm getting error in the "submitOtp" function only, the print in "register" function is running fine

Comment: remove the @csrf_exempt from both view and try. As session is related to csrf.